how to enable input field using playwright
I have a disabled input field, and I want to enable it using Playwright.
 <form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" disabled>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

I want to check if a low permission level user enables it through dev-tools, the submit form would block/fail.
Please note that I'm unable to execute direct API calls to test that.

I think you would be better off with a pure API test instead of using a hacked UI to test that your API doesn't allow "incorrect" behavior.

You are totally right. I forgot to mention I'm unable to execute direct API requests to the server due to our security policies...

You might want to share the page and your code attempt so far so there's enough context to provide a verified, working answer.

I've found a solution using the evaluate method. 
The evaluate method allows you to execute JavaScript code in the context of the browser.
In this case I'm using it to remove the disabled attribute of the input field:
const inputSelector = "#fname";
await page.locator(inputSelector).evaluate((el) => el.removeAttribute("disabled"));


You can use the following approach which follows PW best practices by auto-waiting and locating by user-visible aria role and name.
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" disabled>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body></html>`;

test("input can be disabled with JS", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  const input = page.getByRole("textbox", {name: "First name:"});
  await expect(input).toHaveAttribute("disabled");
  await input.evaluate(el => el.removeAttribute("disabled"));
  await expect(input).not.toHaveAttribute("disabled");
});

However, .evaluate is a slight antipattern and this is a rather strange thing to want to test, since JS console "interaction" isn't a typical user behavior. A savvy user should be able to send the form request by other means than input elements if they really want to. So this could be an XY problem. But if that's the specification you're being forced to test by the powers that be and can't push back, such it is.

It's what I mentioned in a comment, should be a negative API test. However, the OP said they couldn't make direct API requests, which I'm still trying to understand how that's possible.

Yeah, I don't follow how that's possible, and even if the API was blocked I still wouldn't bother testing this. They really should provide more details because the request smells funny. I only posted this because OP's self answer is not very good, using raw page.evaluate and querySelectors which are pretty much no-nos in Playwright tests.

The SUT in this case is very secured and under heavy security policies. security team does not allow direct API req from any clients except its front-end. therefore API testing isn't an option here. this indeed a weird question, this case is rare- but required in my specific case...

You can always spoof the API requests that the browser sends, just saying...
